# JavaScript DataTable disable row auto height non full page

Tags: javascript, html, css, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have a DataTable that I'm trying to configure so that when I set min-height of table it won't increase the height of rows to fill the entire height due to insufficient amount of items on those pages.

```
$("#myTable").DataTable( {
                    "paging":   true,
                    "ordering": false,
                    "searching" : false,
                    "info":     false,
                    "bInfo": false,
                    "bLengthChange": false,
                    "autoHeigth": false,
                    "rowHeigth" : "37px",
                    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                     fixedColumns: {
                        heightMatch: 'none'
                    }
                });
```

What I want is that on non full pages there should be no resize simply 37px rows and rest should be blank.

Comment: .rowHeight is misspelled, see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Opps, missed that "autoHeight" is also misspelled.